# How can I import one Jupyter notebook into another

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Apparently it's possible to [import](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb) one Jupyter notebook into another. The linked page has quite a bit of code to do it.  Am I supposed to add that code to the importing notebook? The page isn't clear about it. It's supposed to be a general solution, so it doesn't make sense to add all that code to all notebooks that import other notebooks. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add all of that code to a notebook if you want.

And yes, you shouldn't do so as a general solution.

A notebook is a complicated structure, as alluded to in the details of the text (I think it's JSON). It can contain python code, it can contain magics - cython, bash, latex and more - which would not be understood by the Python kernel. Essentially you have to replicate a portion of the functionality of the normal Python import process, as natively Python won't understand there is Python code inside an Ipython notebook.

However ... normally if you have a significant amount of Python code you would split it into modules, and then import the modules. These work as normal, because it is a normal Python import.

For example, once the code has been loaded to tell it how to understand what a notebook is, the actual import is only

`import nbpackage.mynotebook`

We can use the same technique with the module import code - `find_notebook` and `NotebookLoader` can be put into a helper module (e.g. `helper.py`), and all you would have to do is, from within your notebook, use `from helper import NotebookFinder`.

I suspect you'd still have to call `sys.meta_path.append(NotebookFinder())` from inside your notebook along with the import.

Here is a specific example of how you can use the import capabilities to create an API drawn from a notebook:

Create a notebook. We'll call it `scanner.ipynb`:

```
import os, sys
def scanner(start):
    for root, dirs,files in os.walk(start):
        # remove any already processed file
        if 'done' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('done')
        for names in files:
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(names)
            # only interested in media files
            if ext == '.mp4' or ext == '.mkv':
                print(name)
```

Create a regular python file called `reuse.py`. **This is your general re-usable Ipython import module**:

```
#! /usr/env/bin python
# *-* coding: utf-8 *-*

import io, os, sys, types
from IPython import get_ipython
from nbformat import read
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell

def find_notebook(fullname, path=None):
    """find a notebook, given its fully qualified name and an optional path

    This turns "foo.bar" into "foo/bar.ipynb"
    and tries turning "Foo_Bar" into "Foo Bar" if Foo_Bar
    does not exist.
    """
    name = fullname.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
    if not path:
        path = ['']
    for d in path:
        nb_path = os.path.join(d, name + ".ipynb")
        if os.path.isfile(nb_path):
            return nb_path
        # let import Notebook_Name find "Notebook Name.ipynb"
        nb_path = nb_path.replace("_", " ")
        if os.path.isfile(nb_path):
            return nb_path

class NotebookLoader(object):
    """Module Loader for Jupyter Notebooks"""
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.shell = InteractiveShell.instance()
        self.path = path

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        """import a notebook as a module"""
        path = find_notebook(fullname, self.path)

        print ("importing Jupyter notebook from %s" % path)

        # load the notebook object
        with io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            nb = read(f, 4)


        # create the module and add it to sys.modules
        # if name in sys.modules:
        #    return sys.modules[name]
        mod = types.ModuleType(fullname)
        mod.__file__ = path
        mod.__loader__ = self
        mod.__dict__['get_ipython'] = get_ipython
        sys.modules[fullname] = mod

        # extra work to ensure that magics that would affect the user_ns
        # actually affect the notebook module's ns
        save_user_ns = self.shell.user_ns
        self.shell.user_ns = mod.__dict__

        try:
          for cell in nb.cells:
            if cell.cell_type == 'code':
                # transform the input to executable Python
                code = self.shell.input_transformer_manager.transform_cell(cell.source)
                # run the code in themodule
                exec(code, mod.__dict__)
        finally:
            self.shell.user_ns = save_user_ns
        return mod

class NotebookFinder(object):
    """Module finder that locates Jupyter Notebooks"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.loaders = {}

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        nb_path = find_notebook(fullname, path)
        if not nb_path:
            return

        key = path
        if path:
            # lists aren't hashable
            key = os.path.sep.join(path)

        if key not in self.loaders:
            self.loaders[key] = NotebookLoader(path)
        return self.loaders[key]
```

Create your specific API file that connects the loader above with the notebook above. Call it `scan_api.py`:

```
# Note the python import here
import reuse, sys

# This is the Ipython hook
sys.meta_path.append(reuse.NotebookFinder())
import scanner
# And now we can drawn upon the code
dir_to_scan = "/username/location"
scanner.scanner(dir_to_scan)
```

Comment: It's not that I have a lot of code. I have two Notebooks and would like to import one Notebook into another. But let's say I want to make one of them into a module and then import it. What does it take to do that?

Comment: @RussAbbott You don't turn the notebook into a module - you turn the import code into a module. Hmm ... you could turn a notebook into a module if you wanted to expose *specific functionality* similar to an API. Then you would create a standard ".py" file using the import capabilities. I see if I can edit my answer with a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Solution with 2 lines of code**

Use '**nbimporter**' package in python for importing another notebook A (or its function) in notebook B.  You can install 'nbimporter' by using the command - pip install nbimporter

Assume there are two Notebooks A.ipynb and B.ipynb. we are trying to import Notebook A (or its function) inside B  Code sample below should solve the issue.

**Inside Notebook B.ipynb**

```
import nbimporter
import A  # or do this --> from A import func1
```

Comment: My problem is that I can't seem to get to the directory where the notebook I want to import is. I have the notebook I want to import (Notebook A) and Notebook I want to import into (Notebook B) in the same Google Drive directory. But when I open Notebook B in colab, the system says (using !pwd) that it is in `/content` and that it can't see Notebook A. All it can see is `sample_data`. How do I put myself in the right directory?

Comment: I also can't `!cd` directly to the correct directory even if I give the full path: `! cd "C:\Users\rabbott\Google Drive\Colab Notebooks"`

Comment: Having tried `nbimporter` for the whole of 2 minutes, it seems a pretty dumb piece of software, as it tries to parse the Markdown parts of the Notebook: ```---> 14     "\n",
     15     "## Actions:\n",
     16     "    \n",

NameError: name 'actions' is not defined``` it clearly does *import* the notebook (no trouble with directories) because it can see the function I'm invoking, but then it is an epic fail.