# Referencing pandas dataframe in a different file

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a jupyter notebook .ipynb that includes the code I wrote to generate some data and a pandas dataframe.

[image: Sample Data]

I need to deploy a web app that renders the location data and allows users to perform some basic analysis. I think Dash Framework offers everything that I am looking for.

My question is how do I reference the pandas dataframe in [app.py](https://github.com/plotly/dash-uber-rides-demo/blob/master/app.py) (file which includes all the front-end code for the Application)

Here's a example from the site [Dash - getting started](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-startej). I need my application code (app.py file) to reference the pandas dataframe from the python notebook file and parse the location data and display on a map/create visualization.

Comment: Can I ask why you would like to access the dataframe from a notebook? I would really recommend storing any python functionality in a .py file, if not in the app.py itself. Trying to reference a notebook seems to introduce unnecessary complexity

Comment: It does seem a little complex - I was just curious if it can be referenced. If I understand you correctly, save the notebook as .py and then reference the dataframe in app.py file?

Comment: It can be referenced. It takes a fair amount of work to set up. See this related question: [How can I import one Jupyter notebook into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382248/how-can-i-import-one-jupyter-notebook-into-another/50382552#50382552)

Comment: Here's a response from the Dash community forum: https://community.plot.ly/t/reference-pandas-dataframe-in-app-py-dash-file/14251/2