# How to implement a reliable cell-by-cell python executor?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I would like to be able to execute cells of python code inside my pre-existing application.
(The code-cells will be appended to a list - but this is not relevant to my question).

My first thought was to try and figure out how Jupyter Notebook approches the cell-execution-task.
Below you can see the code which I currently have:

```
from IPython.testing.globalipapp import get_ipython
from IPython.utils.io import capture_output


ip1 = get_ipython()
ip2 = get_ipython()

def run_cell(ip, cmd):
    with capture_output() as io:
        res = ip.run_cell(cmd)
    res_out = io.stdout
    print('res out', res_out)


run_cell(ip1, 'print("Hello")')
run_cell(ip2, 'print("Test")')
```

This seems like an easy and solid solution, but is there also a possibility to use two ipython-shells at the same time?
The `ip2` is of type `None`, because `get_ipython()` creates a global reference.
Am I even going about this the right way?

Comment: There is an in-built way of exposing the functionality of a Jupyter Notebook - see this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50382552/6414203

Comment: @Alan, on a random note: I'm not using Jupyter Notebook. My program has a GUI with a "Load File" button, a "Run" and "Step" button to execute the next existing cell.

Comment: Doesn't matter - "This is your general re-usable Ipython import module". And you are using Ipython.